# Connecting to network share from Windows Server fails with "organizations's security policies block unauthenticated guest access"

Tags: cmd.exe, network-shares, smb, windows-server, cifs

I am trying to connect from Windows Server to CIFS share.

Either using command

```
net use z: \\ip\sharename /USER:user pasword /PERSISTENT:yes
```

or using mouse click on *This PC* and then *Map Network Drive" ends with message:

> The mapped network drive could not be created because the following error has occurred:
> You can't access this shared folder because your organization's security policies block unauthenticated guest access. These policies help protect your PC from unsafe or malicious devices on the network.

Does anybody know where the problem is and what to change to allow this network shared folder mapping? Wrong credentials? Wrong CIFS server configuration? Some firewall-like settings on Windows Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because of a group policy setting which is not allowing insecure guest log ons.

> Open group policy editor gpedit.msc. Then go to Computer configuration > Administrative Templates > Network > Lanman Workstation then go to Enable insecure guest logins and enable the policy setting.

Source: https://www.techcrumble.net/2018/03/you-cant-access-this-shared-folder-because-your-organizations-security-policies-block-unauthenticated-guest-access/amp/

Hope that helps